# Should "ubuntu" and "linux" be kept on question titles?

Tags: discussion, question-titles

AskUbuntu couldn't be more explicitly about Ubuntu, a specific Linux distribution. (Duh, right?)

With that in mind, should questions like this be renamed?

[How to set up multiple IP addresses?](https://askubuntu.com/q/100715/)

`how to set up multiple IP addresses on my linux?` -> `How to set up multiple IP addresses?`

[How do I set a static IP address?](https://askubuntu.com/q/110735/)

`Set static IP address in Ubuntu` -> `How to set static IP address?`

Isn't there any search tool or trigger in the system to flag this kind of problems or others like [Why are questions no longer titled as questions?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5599/)

Comment: There is no tool in this case, we as a community are it.

Comment: You can, however, use [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/93344/ubuntu-linux-in-question-title)

Comment: @FEichinger That particular query will also catch Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Edubuntu, Ubuntu Studio, Ubuntu One, and other terms commonly appearing in question titles that often ought to be there. (The query is still useful, so long as one understands to watch out for false positives.)

Comment: @EliahKagan That was actually on purpose. Some questions specify DE versions where it's not necessary. And I'd rather catch them as well than ignore them. ;) And as for Ubuntu One and Ubuntu One, I'm probably gonna amend it by a bunch of exceptions at some point, but ... For now it should suffice.

Comment: @FEichinger Thx for the query. I think [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/93357/find-in-ubuntu-pattern-on-askubuntu) will give better results.

Answer (score 9):

Edit that out, make them questions, review the body of the post and improve it to reflect the title.

Daily job, daily task, those have no need to be there. We all know what the site is all about ;)

Answer (score 8):

When it's unclear if something is on Ubuntu, it makes sense for Ubuntu to be in the title. The same is true for Linux, GNU/Linux, and similar terms. This is sometimes the case.

But usually, these terms are superfluous, and take up space, distracting from what's important. So they should usually be edited out.