# How can I or how to?

Tags: discussion, question-titles

In a question title, is it better to put "How to do X" or "How can I do X" if I want to know how to do X?

Comment: Doesn't matter.. I prefer "How do I" "How to do X" just doesn't sound right.. But it doesn't matter.

Comment: Cross-site duplicated http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/213575, also good to read http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5866/, http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5599/169736.

Comment: As a general rule, "How to do X" is strange. You wouldn't really say that in English. Either go for "How can I do X?"/"How do I X?" or "How to X?" depending to the question.

Comment: "How to X?" is grammatically incorrect too.